# MySQL - How to get information from 10 tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 10 columns. Each column is some id. For example:
TaskID colorID typeID....

Now i need to take all this info and "translate" the ids to the "real" content.
The real content is in 10 different tables.table color has color id and color name, table type has id and name and so on.

How can i do in the best way besides 9 subqueries with inner joins?

My solution for now is:

```
select P.*, t3.name
FROM 
(select t1.*, t2.name
from t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id) as P left join on P.id3=t3.i3
```

and so on...

Comment: You will have to query over all 10 tables anyways. A `JOIN` seems to be the best solution to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need subqueries when using joins:

```
SELECT
  t1.Name AS t1_Name,
  t2.Name AS t2_Name,
  t3.Name AS t3_Name,
  ...
FROM ReferencingTable AS r
INNER JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON r.ID1 = t1.ID
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON r.ID2 = t2.ID
INNER JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON r.ID3 = t3.ID
...
;
```

If some of the referencing columns may not contain links and you need to return those rows anyway, you should use outer joins instead, most likely left outer joins:

```
...
FROM ReferencingTable AS r
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON r.ID1 = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON r.ID2 = t2.ID
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner join is the best way.
You cannot forget you are using a relational database, based on relationship between tables.

Comment: You are complicating the query a little bit: You can do as follows:
SELECT t1.name, t2.name2, t3.name3, ....
FROM t1 inner join t2 on t1.id2 = t2.id
inner join t3 on t1.id3 = t3.id  and so on for each table

Answer (score 0):

you shouldnt need to have any subqueries, you can do it all with JOIN's however if your data set is very large you might consider breaking your ID table up into two different tables with 5 FKs each, because performance starts to go down when JOINing more than 7 tables.

Comment: what is the syntax for not subqueries? i published my query in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay to use programmatic solution, then, you can use Java's JPA to define Entity classes which will help you to fetch data of all 10 tables with very ease.

You can also use Ruby's ActiveRecord too for similar ease-of-use.